# Rspec : “Email has already been taken"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I was writing test for registeration form and i got error "Email has already been taken"
I have googled this problem and come up this gem

```
gem 'database_cleaner', git: 'https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner.git'
```

But it still didn't fixed the bug
I may messed up with the database_cleaner setup

spec_helper.rb

```
require 'database_cleaner'
Dir["./spec/support/**/*.rb"].sort.each { |f| require f}
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
    expectations.syntax = :should
  end


  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|

    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner[:active_record].strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

rails_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end
```

factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :identity do |f|
        f.name Faker::Name.name
        f.email Faker::Internet.email
        f.password Faker::Internet.password(4,40)
    end
end
```

identity_spec.rb

```
it "Registration successfully" do
        user = FactoryGirl.create(:identity)
        visit(new_identity_path)
        fill_in('Name', :with => user.name)
        fill_in('Email', :with => user.email)
        fill_in('Password', :with => user.password)
        fill_in('Password confirmation', :with => user.password)
        click_button 'Register'
        page.should have_content("You'r successfully logged in")
    end
```

**UPDATE:**

```
it "Invalid password" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:identity)
    puts "USER Email: #{user.email}"
    visit('/login')
    fill_in('Email', :with => user.email)
    fill_in('Password', :with => "incorrect")
    click_button 'Login'
    page.should have_content("Invalid info")
end

it "Registration successfully" do
    puts "IDENTITY COUNT: #{Identity.count}"
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:identity)
    puts "USER Email: #{user.email}"
    # visit(new_identity_path)
    # fill_in('Name', :with => user.name)
    # fill_in('Email', :with => user.email)
    # fill_in('Password', :with => user.password)
    # fill_in('Password confirmation', :with => user.password)
    # click_button 'Register'
    # page.should have_content("You'r successfully logged in")
end
```

Output

```
USER Email: litzy.legros@rogahnskiles.net
.IDENTITY COUNT: 0
USER Email: litzy.legros@rogahnskiles.net
.
```

.

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` after including the `database_cleaner` gem in your Gemfile? I realize it seems like a no-brainer but we all forget sometimes. :-)

Comment: can u post the output of running that spec

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. So based on the output of the `puts` statements, it looks like `Faker::Internet.email` in your Factory is producing the same email address every time.

Comment: Do you know how to make Faker to produce different email for every example.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you might have it *slightly* misconfigured.

Try putting `require 'database_cleaner'` in your `spec_helper.rb` file.

And then include `require 'spec_helper'` in your `rails_helper.rb` file.

If that doesn't fix it, then please include the rest of your `spec_helper.rb` and `rails_helper.rb` files in your question.

---

### UPDATE

As far as I can tell, everything looks good in your helper files. The only difference I see between your implementation and my own is that you've got the strategy defined with:

```
DatabaseCleaner[:active_record].strategy = :transaction
```

whereas mine is simply:

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
```

I don't think that would be the issue but it's worth a shot.

If that doesn't fix it, can you throw a couple of `puts` statements in your  spec tests and let us know the output? Like so:

```
puts "IDENTITY COUNT: #{Identity.count}"
user = FactoryGirl.create(:identity)
puts "USER EMAIL: #{user.email}"
```

This will let us know two things:

1. is `database_cleaner` actually not working (count should be 0 if it is working)
2. is `Faker` using the same exact email address every time it's used.

Comment: OK. Please update your question with the entirety of your `spec_helper.rb` and `rails_helper.rb` files and we'll go from there.

Comment: Also, did you run `bundle install` after including the gem in your Gemfile?

Comment: It didn't work, i have updated my question and did what you said. Thanks for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

Capybara tests should not use transactions. Turn off transactions in `rails_helper.`rb with:

`config.use_transactional_fixtures = false`

The [database_cleaner docs](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example) explain why:

> You'll typically discover a feature spec is incorrectly using transaction instead of truncation strategy when the data created in the spec is not visible in the app-under-test.
>
> A frequently occurring example of this is when, after creating a user in a spec, the spec mysteriously fails to login with the user. This happens because the user is created inside of an uncommitted transaction on one database connection, while the login attempt is made using a separate database connection. This separate database connection cannot access the uncommitted user data created over the first database connection due to transaction isolation.